# JSF managed bean called multiple times in a forEach loop

Tags: hibernate, jsf, managed-bean

i have one index.xhtml

```
<c:forEach items="${postsBean.homePagePosts}" var="category">
 #{category.name}
 <c:forEach items="#{category.posts}" var="post">
      #{post.postTitle}
      #{post.user.userName}
      #{post.rating}
      #{post.totalReads}
 </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

one managed bean named *PostsBean.java* having a method *homePagePosts()* that uses hibernate to fetch records from the database and returns a List

```
public List getHomePagePosts() {
    session = helper.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("method called "+ i++ +" times");
    List posts;
    List categoryList = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<String, Object> categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    String HQL = "from Posts as post where post.category= :category order by post.totalReads desc";
    Query query = session.createQuery(HQL);

    Posts post;
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.BUSINESS);
    posts = query.list();

    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.BUSINESS);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
        categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.EDUCATION);
    posts = query.list();
    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.EDUCATION);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
        categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.ENTERTAINMENT);
    posts = query.list();
    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.ENTERTAINMENT);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
        categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.HEALTH);
    posts = query.list();
    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.HEALTH);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
        categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.POLITICS);
    posts = query.list();
    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.POLITICS);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
        categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.SKILLS);
    posts = query.list();
    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.SKILLS);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
        categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.TECHNOLOGY);
    posts = query.list();
    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.TECHNOLOGY);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
        categoryName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    query.setString("category", TextitConstants.SPORTS);
    posts = query.list();
    if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
        categoryName.put("name", TextitConstants.SPORTS);
        categoryName.put("posts", posts);
        categoryList.add(categoryName);
    }
    return categoryList;
}
```

The issue is that the method postsBean.homePagePosts is called multiple times before the index.xhtml page is rendered.  it should be called only once and return a list to the forEach loop and then the forEach loop will iterate the list and display the results...

following are the test results that i found running the website with variable amount of data in the table

- 5 records = 26 times execution
- 4 records = 22 times execution
- 3 records = 16 times execution
- 2 records = 10 times execution
- 1 records = 7 times execution
- 0 records = 1 times execution

u can clearly see that there is no symmetry in the execution of the method and the number of records in the database

one thing to be noted...i didnt close the Hibernate session in the method postsBean.homePagePosts() because if i do, the EL **#{post.user.userName}** gives an exception as the session is closed. (post.user is an object of class User)

Comment: What is the Reference Implementation of JSF you are using? What Version? What is the SCOPE of the ManagedBean `PostsBean.java`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Comment: Keep your GETers simple and easy. Try to do the DB fetching in some kind of init method.